# Create result from double table query with missing record

Tags: php, mysql

The two tables are basically identical with a user id, date and count.

I need to get results for both tables via user id, but match the dates. If a date is missing from either table (ie it is in one table but not the other) I need to assign a 0 for "count" for that returned result. Can this be done in the query or do I need to do this in PHP as well?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: The filling-in of missing date rows, you might be able to create synthetic rows in a query, but it would be more straight forward to do that in a script. It's certainly not hard to create an array of dates: https://3v4l.org/KqYsV

Comment: This is a FULL OUTER JOIN, for which MySQL does not have native support, but which can, obviously, be easily emulated.

Comment: I was just going to query each table independently and build an array, then compare both arrays. I was just hoping it could all be done via a query. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building an array for both table results, then picking the bigger array via count and running a loop through it comparing keys to the smaller array. Thanks everyone for their insight!

Answer (score -1):

You can select from both tables with inner join, and after that you can add condition with WHERE statement, like WHERE date != null, or date != ''. 
If you'd like to read more about inner join, this is your site below:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: The problem is that if there is a missing record for that date, I don't want to drop it, I want to create it and assign 0 as the count for that record. With inner join won't it drop it? Thanks for the help!